# Add ASP.NET web service while impersonating credentials

Tags: asp.net, web-services, impersonation

I have a web reference that I do not have access to through my windows credentials, but do through impersonation.  Unfortunately, I cannot update or add the reference because of my lack of credentials.  When the service is added, it works fine when I set impersonation to true and add credentials.

Is there a way to impersonate a credentials when adding/updating a web service reference through the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by clicking on Visual Studio and clicking run-as, then entering the credentials I wanted to impersonate.  After that I was able to update my service.